# Do wordpress tags urls affect SEO?

Tags: seo, wordpress

Wordpress generates [url](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_tag_link/) for each tag.

I read a discussion where someone says these urls are "not important" and they negatively affect SEO. Is this true?

Comment: @gael Sorry, didn't find that before posting question.

Comment: no problem @Matt and as you will see in the answer, there is no True or False statement to your question. Depends on your global SEO strategy. Good luck ;)